# How can I add a package date time when I want to install my project using MAVEN?

Tags: java, maven, maven-3

My project call shop,now every time when I install my project using maven tool,I can get the jar call shop-0.0.1.jar.Now I want to add two propertys to the jar which can tell me when the jar is installed and what version the jar is. And no matter how many time I install,I want the jar's name is unchanged which always called shop-0.0.1.jar.So I try to change my pom.xml,but still not work.How to fix it?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<artifactId>shop</artifactId>
<version>v2.0-${build.time}</version>
<name>shop</name>
<build> 
    <finalName>${project.artifactId}_0.0.1</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>timestamp-property</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>timestamp-property</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <name>build.time</name>
                        <pattern>yyyy_MM_dd_HH_mm</pattern>
                        <locale>zh_CN</locale>
                        <timeZone>Asia/Shanghai</timeZone>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin> 
     </project>
```

Comment: So first the `<finalName>..</finalName>` only changes the name for the `target/` directory nothing else... it's strange to see because your version `<version>...</version>` which contains a property which does not really work. If you like to keep the version all the time the same (which does not make sense from my point of view) you can simply replace the `<version>v2.0-${build.time}</version>` with `<version>0.0.1</version>` and remove the `<finalName>..</finalName>`tag...

Comment: If I replace the <version>v2.0-${build.time}</version> with <version>0.0.1</version> and remove the <finalName>..</finalName>tag,I can not know  the install date time and the inner version call v2.0. The version 0.0.1 may be the file name to every one and the v2.0 is only embedded in the jar.

Comment: Why do you need the install date time? The install is not really an install time it's the time you have build the jar via `mvn install` I would recommend to use real versions numbers for such purpose... maybe you can describe more in detail what exactly the problem is?

Comment: I just want the jar's name unchanged and contains  mvn install datetime.If I use <version>v2.0-${build.time}</version>,then every time I update the project I have to delete the old jar and update the new jar instead of upload it directly.

Answer (score 0):

Two copies of the same non-SNAPSHOT version of the jar should be identical as that is assumed by maven.

In other words you cannot do what you want to do in a released version.

You can, however, if you use snapshot versions.

Comment: How to use snapshot versions?Like what khmarbaise say?

Comment: You may want to read up on how maven works, because it is heavily opinionated on how things should be done.